# The performance of k-means evaluated by different metrics

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to evaluate the clusters generated by K-means with different metrics, but I am not sure about whether the results are good or not.

I have 40 documents to cluster in 6 categories.
I first converted them into tf-idf vectors, then I clustered them by K-means (k = 6). Finally, I tried to evaluate the results by different metrics.

Because I have the real labels of the documents, I tried to calculate the  F1 score and accuracy. But I also want to know the performance for the metrics that do not need real labels such as silhouette score.

For F1 score and accuracy, the results are about 0.65 and 0.88 respectively, while for the silhouette score, it is only about 0.05, which means I may have overlapping clusters.

In this case, can I say that the results are acceptable? Or should I handle the overlapping issue by trying other methods instead of tf-idf to represent the documents or other algorithms to cluster?

Comment: Try in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

With such tiny data sets, you really *need* to use a measure that is **adjusted for chance**.

Do the following: label each document randomly with an integer 1..6
What F1 score to you get? Now repeat this 100x times, what is the best result you get? A completely random result can score pretty well on such tiny data!

Because of this problem, the **standard measure** used in clustering it's the **adjusted Rand index (ARI)**. A similar adjustment also exists for NMI: Adjusted Mutual Information or AMI. But AMI is much less common.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I'm not familiar with ARI, at what level of ARI indicating the clustering performance is acceptable, more than 0.5?

Comment: Since you have a "true" labeling, just use the labels. What a good ARI is depends on the quality of these labels and the difficulty. On an easy toy data set, ARI should be >0.95.